# Attached css only seen by AdminsGroup

Tags: 2013, css, custom-masterpage

Working on a SP2013 migrated from 2010. I added a custom css to the `seattle.master` using the `Designer`, the result:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteAssets/CustomStyles.css" />
```

It works, even if [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn985879.aspx) tells to add it followings:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/CustomStyles.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

I also tried to edit the masterpage by hand, but it says that it is not allowed.

The Problem is that the css is loaded only for the users of the `Portal Administrators`. Debugging by another user there is no css and no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure both your master page and your css file are published and approved, so all users can see the update.

Other users probably don't see the css file call because they are getting the previous version of the master page.

Comment: I didn't know about the approvment.... Taking a look on the web I found how to approve it, but when i try it tells `The File cannot moved, deleted, renamed or edited`.

Comment: Well, it told the error, but it approved....lol

Comment: typically you want to avoid editing the default master pages. it's better to make a copy, rename it to something you'd like, and then make the switch